# gksudo nautilus - incorrect password

Tags: nautilus, authentication

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running on my office PC. I have a STANDARD user working on it (with limited privileges).

I'm looking at the screen through Team Viewer and I am trying to run **gksudo -u AdminUser nautilus** but it keeps reporting

> incorrect password... try again

I can't figure out why...

Suspecting my password must be corrupt, I tried running software updates and it works fine. What is the solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that user in the sudoers list?

Comment: It may be expecting the root password (which isn't set by default) - run `gksu-properties` and make sure the 'Authentication mode' is set to 'sudo' not 'su'

Comment: @LuísdeSousa AdminUser is the initial user that was created when the OS was installed. I was using it just fine until today. I don't know if the OS user accounts has got corrupt.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean by "standard user with limited privileges". If your password was corrupt you couldn't run updates.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Thank you for your inputs. AdminUser is the initial user who has sudo privileges. The user account 'HatcheryUser' is one who has limited privileges on the OS. I added this user so that they wouldn't mess up certain settings on the OS. And you're right about the updates. That's what is worrying me. I can run updates but not authenticate as GKSUDO NAUTILUS. I think the OS is corrupt for some weird reason. I'm not too sure now. But it's a new installation - may be about 3 weeks after formatting...

Comment: I very much doubt this is a corruption issue. From a session with the HatcheryUser try to launch a new session with AdminUser: sudo su AdminUser

Comment: Thank you @LuísdeSousa. I did something like your comment and got it working. I first did **su AdminUser** and gave the password. Then I was able to run **apt-get install -f** and patch whatever was incomplete. But as a result it has removed some of my Lazarus files. It's broken now. But I think the question of running updates is solved. Please post your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to access the **AdminUser** account in a wrong way, or perhaps entering the wrong password. From a session with the **HatcheryUser** try to launch a new session with **AdminUser**:

```
sudo su AdminUser
```

This will prompt you for a password, the one from **HatcheryUser**. If the latter is in the sudoers list you will then enter an admin session from where you'll be able to run all the dangerous stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the input. After doing my tasks as AdminUser, how do leave the session and return to the HatcheryUser?

Comment: Just type "exit".